# Why can my Server not receive any data from a readable socketChannel?

Tags: java, buffer, nio, socketchannel

I'm trying to build a server client application.

The clients can connect to the server and are correctly registered.
When a client writes data to the channel which connects client and server, the server cannot read any data.
The selectorKey isReadable triggers the method responsable for storing the incomming message. But it is always empty.
Any idea why that is?

Client:

```
package Client;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import routing.RoutingEntry;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.*;

   

    public class Client {
    
        private final String clientName;
    
        SocketChannel connection;
        ByteBuffer readBuffer;
        ByteBuffer writeBuffer;
        int serverPort;
        Selector selector;
        Set<RoutingEntry> routingTable = new HashSet<>();
    
    
        public Client(int serverPort, String clientName) {
            this.clientName = clientName;
            this.serverPort = serverPort;
            this.readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
            this.writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
    
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Client client = new Client(5001, "Client_1");
            client.connect();
            while (true) client.sendMessage();
        }
    
        public void connect() {
            try {
                connection = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), serverPort));
                System.out.println(connection);
                selector = Selector.open();
                connection.configureBlocking(false);
                connection.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                routingTable.add(new RoutingEntry(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), connection.socket().getLocalPort(), clientName, 0, null));
                System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(routingTable));
                while (!connection.finishConnect()) {
                    System.out.println("Connecting...");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
  
    
        public void sendMessage() {
            System.out.print("Message to send: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String msg = sc.nextLine().trim();
            try {
                writeBuffer.put(msg.getBytes());
                connection.write(writeBuffer);
                writeBuffer.clear();
    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Server:

```
package server;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import routing.RoutingEntry;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class Server {

    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> incomingMessages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    Set<RoutingEntry> routingTable;

    int serverPort;
    String serverIP;
    String serverName;
    Selector selector;
    ServerSocketChannel ssc;
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);


    public Server(int serverPort, String serverName) {
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
        this.serverName = serverName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server(5001, "Server_1");
        server.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        initRoutingTable();
        try {
            selector = Selector.open();
            ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            ssc.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverIP, serverPort));
            ssc.configureBlocking(false);
            ssc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("In loop");
                selector.select();
                Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> iter = selectedKeys.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {

                    SelectionKey key = iter.next();

                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        registerNewClient();
                    }

                    if (key.isReadable()) {
                        storeMessage(key);
                    }
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ignore) {}
    }


    public void storeMessage(SelectionKey key) {
        // read message
        System.out.println("in storeMessage");
        try {
            SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            int count = client.read(buffer);
            System.out.println(count);
            if (count == -1)
            {
                client.close();
                return;
            }
            String msg = new String(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.limit());
            System.out.println("Message: " + msg);
            incomingMessages.put(msg);
            buffer.clear();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            key.cancel();
            System.out.println("Lost connection to client.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void registerNewClient() {
        // establish connection to client
        try {
            SocketChannel client = ssc.accept();
            System.out.println("new client connected: " + client.getRemoteAddress().toString().replace("/", ""));
            client.configureBlocking(false);
            client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            System.out.println("connection fully done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   

    private void initRoutingTable() {
        routingTable = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            serverIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            routingTable.add(new RoutingEntry(serverIP, serverPort, serverName, 0, null));
            System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(routingTable));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output in `storeMessage()` : "Message: "

Comment: First you should not use a global ByteBuffer as it will be shared by all clients. Then buffer.limit() should be buffer.position() (or count if not shared) when you create your String. Try also to print the value of count to see if you really read something.